# The closed form for the number of 2-element subsets of the power set of a set with fixed overal size

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am looking for a closed form for the sum below

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{r} \frac{1}{2-\delta_{k, r-k}} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{r-k} $$

where $\delta_{k, r-k}$ is the Kronecker delta. I'd appreciate any helps in finding a closed-form solution for this sum.

To my understanding, this is basically equivalent to finding a closed-form solution to the following problem:

Given a set $S$ with size $|S|=n$, what is the number of two-element subsets of $\mathcal{P}(S)$, $\{A, B\} \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ such that $|A|+|B| = r$  for a fixed $r$.

I tried to use Wolfram Alpha, but it is given me this for the case where we count ordered pairs $(A, B)$ instead of sets (i.e. the sum if we ignore $\frac{1}{2-\delta_{k, r-k}}$), which contains factorial of a negative integer(!!) (and I don't know how to specify in Wolfram that $n>r>0$ and both are integers):

$$ \frac{(-1)^r (-2n+r-1)!}{(-2n-1)!r!} $$

Comment: Are you wanting to count the number of *ordered pairs* $(A,B)$ with the property that $|A|+|B|=r$?  Or are you wanting to count the number of *sets* $\{A,B\}$ with the property that $|A|+|B|=r$.  Your summation counts the ordered pairs, not the sets.  If wanting to count the number of sets, then you have overcounted each situation where $A$ and $B$ are nonequal twice.  Further, if wanting to count the number of sets, then wouldn't you consider $\{A,B\}$ to be a one element set in the case that $A=B$?

Comment: Have a look at [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for pointing it out. I guess either of them would work for me, as I'd just divide the answer for ordered pairs by 2 and add half of the product for $k=r-k$ case to get the answer for sets, but I actually want the answer for sets. I corrected the post accordingly (please do point it out if I didn't!).

Comment: @drhab I think that's the answer

Comment: @ArnaudD. Since apparently what I was looking for was just the Vandermondt identity, I think it may be a duplicate.